# D3 - Stacked bar update, axis update but not bars

Tags: d3.js

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-bar-stacked-update?embed=1&file=index.js&hideNavigation=1

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart that updates using the D3 Update Pattern.

I have the axis updating but the bars dont update

The update function gets called, the data updates and the update function works when the page first loads

I did try to include the code here but I always get errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the groups then the bars:

```
const u = chart.selectAll('.layer')
      .data(stackedSeries);

      u.exit().remove()

     const bars = u.enter()
      .append('g')
      .classed('layer', true)
      .style('fill', (d,i)=>{
        return colors[i]
      })
      .merge(u)
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data((d) => d);

      bars.exit().remove()

      x.domain(graphData.map((d) => d.date))

      y.domain([0, d3.max(stackedSeries, (d) => d3.max(d, (d) => d[1]))]);

      bars.enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', (d) => x(d.data.date))
      .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
      .attr('y', (d) => y(d[1]))
      .attr('height', (d) => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))

      bars.merge(bars)
        .attr('x', (d) => x(d.data.date))
        .attr('width', x.bandwidth())
        .attr('y', (d) => y(d[1]))
        .attr('height', (d) => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))
```